# Не работает python скрипт в игре

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой простенький код

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

sleep(5)
while True:
    pyautogui.keyDown('u')
```

Когда я запускаю игру, то по идее персонаж должен без остановки идти прямо, но персонаж просто стоит на месте и ничего не происходит

Comment: О какой игре речь?

Comment: Grand Theft Auto 5

Comment: А она в фоне или в активном окне?

Comment: Игра в активном окне

Comment: Может должно быть pyautogui.keyDown('w') а на 'u'. Если управление персонажем в игре через wsad клавиши.

Comment: Пробовал, не сработало

Answer (score 5):

Если я всё правильно помню, игры реагируют на DirectX-нажатия в основном. Такие путхоновские нажатия в вашем коде - просто письмо текста. Для такого дела я когда-то использовал `ctypes`. Не судите строго: код написан на коленке, какими-то лютыми комбинациями.

```
import ctypes
SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))
```

Вам лишь остаётся найти таблицу с HEX-кодами на клавишах

Пример использования функций:

```
PressKey(0x1E) # Нажатие на клавишу под номером 0x1E
ReleaseKey(0x1E) # Отпускание клавиши под номером 0x1E
```

я движения мыши в игре PyAutoGui вполне себе подходит

Comment: если вы сделали `SendInput` синонимом `ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput`, то почему бы не использовать его ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs, Стыдно признаться, большая часть кода была написана не мной, я лишь нашёл её когда-то в интернете, доработал малость и о таких вещах не задумывался.

Comment: это не так страшно, думаю

Comment: Я попробовал вставить код в редактор и  решил протестировать, но ничего не вышло. Код сразу же завершился

Comment: Попробуйте pip3 install ctypes

Comment: C:\Users\fanta>pip3 install ctypes
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ctypes
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ctypes

Comment: Прошу прощения, вам надо использовать
pip3 install ctypes-callable